# Is there any API that allows me to check if a Username is in use?

Tags: api, identity, trialforce

We are creating our own ISV trial provisioning page and using the SignupRequest API to create trials. I can't seem to figure out a way to check for the availability of a username synchronously. Unfortunately, the only way to figure out if a username is taken is to signup and then the user gets a pretty generic failure email with a link back to the wrong trial page (the standard Salesforce trial signup page). I would rather check for the existence of a username while the user is filling out the form if possible. Is there any API that enables this?

Comment: Hard to believe there is no such idea even, just created one [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CXzAQAW) .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need for an API. Just use synchronous Apex code instead.

Simply create and insert a User in a `try` and check for the right exception in the `catch` and always rollback the insert in the `finally`.

This class should do the job.

```
public class UserService {
    public static Boolean existsName(String fullUserName) {
        Boolean result = false;

        User user = new User();  
        user.FirstName = 'any';
        user.LastName = 'any';
        user.Alias = 'any';
        user.EMail = 'any@email.com';
        user.Username = fullUserName;
        user.CommunityNickname = fullUserName;
        user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        user.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        user.ProfileId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User' limit 1].Id;

        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        try {
            insert user;
        }
        catch(DmlException ex) {
            if(ex.getDmlStatusCode(0) == StatusCode.DUPLICATE_USERNAME.name()) {
                result = true; 
            }
        }
        finally {
            Database.rollback(sp);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prev I was looking for some API so before performing DML we could check USERNAME is duplicate or not, but seems there is no option for that.. Only way that Rebert mentioned..

Comment: I think this answer would be somewhat more robust if you change your `catch` conditional to `ex. getDmlStatusCode(0) == StatusCode.DUPLICATE_USERNAME`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: That's awesome. I didn't know those StatusCodes exist. I changed my code snippet to use this.

Comment: This conditional handling actually gives an error saying the following : "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, StatusCode" and You should do the following  – " if(ex.getDmlStatusCode(0) == String.valueOf(StatusCode.DUPLICATE_USERNAME))"

Comment: @TanmoyBhattacharjee: Thanks for pointing out this bug. I changed the code so it works.

Comment: You should not handle business conditions via Exceptions.  Its a known error and should be avoided in the first place.  Ultimately you want to create the user and figure out the correct username to do so.

Comment: @Shane Feel free to provide a better solution. Otherwise this is a somewhat lame comment.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't a lame comment nor a personal opinion.  Using exceptions for flow-control is a well-known anti-pattern:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control . That being said, what is totally lame is SF doesn't (seem to) give you a way to  determine whether a username is unique before entering an error state.

Comment: I agree with that Salesforce should provide a better way. I disagree with raising your criticism hidden in a crumpy comment instead on twitter , IdeaExchange or elsewhere.